# Parse.com for Windows Phone 8 - get_LocalSettings() not implemented

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform, storage, notimplementedexception

I am using Parse.com storage service for Windows Phone 8. When I try to initialize

```
ParseClient.Initialize("MY_APP_ID","MY_NET_ID");
```

I am getting this exception:

```
   System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.get_LocalSettings()
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper..ctor()
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.SettingsWrapper.get_Wrapper()
   at Parse....
```

I am targeting Windows Phone 8 and I found out that WP8 is not supporting LocalSettings, just WP8.1.
When I target it to WP8.1 everything is working fine.
But...
I have another application for WP8 in which I am using Parse and everything is working fine.
How can I avoid this problem?

Just for info: App which does not work was built for WP7.1 and than upgraded to WP8, and another which works fine was from beginnig targeting WP8.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If someone has the same problem, just install older version of parse package in Nuget.

```
PM> unInstall-Package parse
PM> Install-Package parse -Version 1.2.16
```